# These words have the same meaning?

Tags: word-meaning, difference, synonyms

I found this quote on the internet: "“He is putting by some money for a car". 
Can you explain me if "putting by some money" have the same meaning of "save money"? is it synonyms?

Comment: Have you tried looking in a dictionary, or typing **put by meaning** into a search engine such as Google?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

Putting some money away
Putting money aside
Putting by some money

All mean the same thing: saving some money.